# Speed on querying view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view

Say, I have a view, call it view1,  with data from 2010 to 2015.
and another view, call it view2, with data from 2011 to 2012.

i wanna know if there will be a big difference on querying the 2 views in the following cases.

```
1, select * from view2;
2, select * from view1 where date between 2011 and 2012;
```

The result will be the same set of data.
if selecting data from views with certain conditions will really slow down the speed, why? If not, please also explain. Thank you.

Comment: I believe performance/execution plan may also depend on whether the view is aggregating values or is just a straight `select stuff as other_stuff where some_condition=1` type query using the MERGE algorithm [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html). You can look at [`explain`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) to get a better idea of how it plans to run the query.

Comment: You can always test it.

Comment: Yes. I can. But I also want to understand why. :)

Comment: Please read this, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ , and pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question to give more details. As it stands your question is unanswerable. Recent versions of the MySQL query planner generally handle views as if they were subqueries, so you may be able to take advantage of underlying indexes in the source tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `select * from view2;`. You need full-table scan anyway.

Even if you use `select * from view1 where date between 2011 and 2012;` smart query optimizer will know that you're selecting more than 20% of entire table and won't use index on `date` at all (if exists any)

Comment: I think there will be no index on any virtual table in MySQL.

Comment: That's not necessarily how MySQL will handle the view. If it is using the MERGE engine, it effectively is just combining SQL from the view's definition with the rest of your code.